# Heroku Serving Localhost URL (127.0.0.1:8000) in Ajax API URLs in Django App

Tags: django, heroku, localhost, django-staticfiles, static-files

I'm currently working on a Django project and it's hosted on Heroku from GitHub. The front-end is served via Ajax calls to an API.

```
let myurl = "/api/properties/";

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        url:myurl,
        method:'GET',
        success: function(result){
            ....
        }
    });
```

Everything works well on localhost, but on Heroku, I keep getting the error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/properties/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My API URL has no `http://127.0.0.1:8000` on GitHub but on Heroku it has it after analyzing the source code on the Sources tab on Chrome:

```
let myurl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/properties/";
    
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url:myurl,
            method:'GET',
            success: function(result){
                ....
            }
        });
```

I don't understand why my app's API URL isn't taking the domain URL `https://appname.herokuapp.com/api/properties/` and it's across all the Ajax API URLs on the Django app. I have cleared my browser cache, opened the app in 'incognito mode' and even redeployed the project several times but not change. Kindly help me debug this and understand where the localhost URL is coming from.

**UPDATE**

My property API view

```
@login_required(login_url='Login' )
def AllProperties(request):
    return render(request, 'Dashboard - Properties.html')

class PropertyAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PropertiesSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the properties
        created by the currently authenticated user.
        """
        user = self.request.user
        return RentalProperties.objects.filter(created_by=user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """
        This view should create a new property listing
        for the currently authenticated user.
        """
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)

class PropertyDetailAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = RentalProperties.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PropertiesSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated , IsOwnerOrReadOnly]
```

Property API URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/properties/', views.AllProperties, name="AllProperties"),
    path('api/properties/', views.PropertyAPI.as_view(), name="PropertyListAPI"),
    path('api/properties/<int:pk>/', views.PropertyDetailAPI.as_view(), name="PropertyDetailAPI"),
]
```

Comment: Can you share more of the template/script that serves your front-end? Are you using Django templateing/rendering generate the URL?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington the code provided is a snippet of the whole JS script. Its a long code so that's why I didn't post it all here. But all scripts with API endpoints being served via AJAX are all affected. So I cant perform any CRUD functions. Django URLs are all fine and I can navigate between pages. And yes I'm using Django templating to generate the URL.

Comment: Can you show how the URLs are generated in your templates or sent to your JS? Just an example showing one would do

Comment: @IainShelvington check my update. Is that what you are requesting?